# Jquery - copying an input to a div with keyup paste, having an issue with autofilled data

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am using `('keyup paste', function()` to fill a `<div>`, but I do not know what to do when someone uses autofill. Also I am using cookies for a previous visitors that filled out the form. So I would like to also know how to fill the `div` when someone uses autofill or has the field populated with a cookie.

Here is my current script:

```
$(function () {
     $('#Website').on('keyup paste', function() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      var str = $(self).val();
      $("#viewer").text(str.replace(/^http\:\/\//, ''));
    }, 0)
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
     $('#Website').on('keyup blur paste', function() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      var str = $(self).val();
      $("#viewer").text(str.replace(/^http\:\/\//, ''));
    }, 0)
    })
});
```